# Why is datatables JQuery plugin showing duplicates of all my buttons in my MVC web app?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, datatables

I am building an MVC web app using a bootstrap template I found online. I have been taking bits and pieces from the template to build my website design, and took some of their code for a datatable. When I paste it in, the paginate buttons don't work and each button is shown twice.

Here is my _Layout.cshtml file:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Issue Tracker | @ViewData["Title"]</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,400i,700&display=fallback">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../dist/plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../dist/plugins/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../dist/plugins/icheck-bootstrap/icheck-bootstrap.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../dist/plugins/jqvmap/jqvmap.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../dist/css/adminlte.min.css?v=3.2.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../dist/plugins/overlayScrollbars/css/OverlayScrollbars.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../dist/plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../dist/plugins/summernote/summernote-bs4.min.css">

    @RenderSection("Scripts2", false)

    <script nonce="f08f87fb-ed24-4db1-9ae1-3fbbff03e13b">(function (w, d) { !function (a, e, t, r) { a.zarazData = a.zarazData || {}, a.zarazData.executed = [], a.zaraz = { deferred: [] }, a.zaraz.q = [], a.zaraz._f = function (e) { return function () { var t = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments); a.zaraz.q.push({ m: e, a: t }) } }; for (const e of ["track", "set", "ecommerce", "debug"]) a.zaraz[e] = a.zaraz._f(e); a.zaraz.init = () => { var t = e.getElementsByTagName(r)[0], z = e.createElement(r), n = e.getElementsByTagName("title")[0]; for (n && (a.zarazData.t = e.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].text), a.zarazData.x = Math.random(), a.zarazData.w = a.screen.width, a.zarazData.h = a.screen.height, a.zarazData.j = a.innerHeight, a.zarazData.e = a.innerWidth, a.zarazData.l = a.location.href, a.zarazData.r = e.referrer, a.zarazData.k = a.screen.colorDepth, a.zarazData.n = e.characterSet, a.zarazData.o = (new Date).getTimezoneOffset(), a.zarazData.q = []; a.zaraz.q.length;) { const e = a.zaraz.q.shift(); a.zarazData.q.push(e) } z.defer = !0; for (const e of [localStorage, sessionStorage]) Object.keys(e || {}).filter((a => a.startsWith("_zaraz_"))).forEach((t => { try { a.zarazData["z_" + t.slice(7)] = JSON.parse(e.getItem(t)) } catch { a.zarazData["z_" + t.slice(7)] = e.getItem(t) } })); z.referrerPolicy = "origin", z.src = "/cdn-cgi/zaraz/s.js?z=" + btoa(encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(a.zarazData))), t.parentNode.insertBefore(z, t) }, ["complete", "interactive"].includes(e.readyState) ? zaraz.init() : a.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", zaraz.init) }(w, d, 0, "script"); })(window, document);</script>

</head>
<body class="hold-transition sidebar-mini layout-fixed">
    <div class="preloader flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <img class="animation__shake" src="../../dist/img/IssueTrackerLogo.png" alt="IssueTrackerLogo" height="60" width="60">
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">

        <nav class="main-header navbar navbar-expand navbar-white navbar-light">

            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" data-widget="pushmenu" href="#" role="button"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <!-- Right navbar links -->
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

                <partial name="_LoginPartial" />

            </ul>
        </nav>
        <!-- /.navbar -->
        <!-- Main Sidebar Container -->
        <aside class="main-sidebar sidebar-dark-primary elevation-4">
            <!-- Brand Logo -->
            <a class="brand-link">
                <img src="../../dist/img/IssueTrackerLogo.png" alt="IssueTracker Logo" class="brand-image img-circle elevation-3" style="opacity: .8">
                <span class="brand-text font-weight-light">Issue Tracker</span>
            </a>
            <!-- Sidebar -->
            <div class="sidebar">
                <!-- Sidebar user (optional) -->
                <div class="user-panel mt-3 pb-3 mb-3 d-flex">
                    <div class="image">
                        <img src="../../dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg" class="img-circle elevation-2" alt="User Image">
                    </div>
                    <div class="info">
                        <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Profile" class="d-block">Alexander Pierce</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- SidebarSearch Form -->
                <div class="form-inline">
                    <div class="input-group" data-widget="sidebar-search">
                        <input class="form-control form-control-sidebar" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <button class="btn btn-sidebar">
                                <i class="fas fa-search fa-fw"></i>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Sidebar Menu -->
                <nav class="mt-2">
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-sidebar flex-column" data-widget="treeview" role="menu" data-accordion="false">
                        <!-- Add icons to the links using the .nav-icon class
                        with font-awesome or any other icon font library -->
                        <li class="nav-header">Pages</li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="nav-icon fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
                                <p>
                                    Dashboard
                                </p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Projects" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="nav-icon fas fa-bars"></i>
                                <p>
                                    My Projects
                                </p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Tickets" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="nav-icon fas fa-copy"></i>
                                <p>
                                    My Tickets
                                </p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Profile" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="nav-icon fas fa-user"></i>
                                <p>
                                    User Profile
                                </p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a onclick="NewTab()" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="nav-icon fas fa-cubes"></i>
                                <p>
                                    Repository
                                </p>
                            </a>
                            <script>function NewTab() {
                                    window.open("https://github.com/tobinryan/IssueTracker", "_blank");
                                }</script>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-header">Actions</li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="CreateTicket" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="nav-icon fas fa-edit"></i>
                                <p>Create a Ticket</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="ViewTickets" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="nav-icon fas fa-book"></i>
                                <p>View All Tickets</p>
                                <span class="badge badge-info right">6</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="ManageRoles" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="nav-icon fas fa-list"></i>
                                <p>Manage Roles</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="ManageUsers" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="nav-icon fas fa-users"></i>
                                <p>Manage Users</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <!-- /.sidebar-menu -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.sidebar -->
        </aside>

        <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
            <section class="content-header">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row mb-2">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
                                <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                                <li class="breadcrumb-item active">@ViewData["Title"]</li>
                            </ol>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
            </section>

            <!-- Main content -->
            <section class="content">

                @RenderBody()

            </section>
            <!-- /.content -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.content-wrapper -->
        <footer class="main-footer layout-footer-fixed">
            <div class="float-right d-none d-sm-block">
                <b>Version</b> 4.2.0
            </div>
            <strong>Copyright &copy; 2022 <a href="https://github.com/tobinryan/IssueTracker">Github</a>.</strong> All rights reserved.
        </footer>
    </div>
    <!-- ./wrapper -->
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="../../dist/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="../../dist/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script>$.widget.bridge('uibutton', $.ui.button)</script>

    <!-- Bootstrap 4 -->
    <script src="../../dist/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <script src="../../dist/plugins/chart.js/Chart.min.js"></script>

    <script src="../../dist/plugins/sparklines/sparkline.js"></script>

    <script src="../../dist/plugins/jqvmap/jquery.vmap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../dist/plugins/jqvmap/maps/jquery.vmap.usa.js"></script>

    <script src="../../dist/plugins/jquery-knob/jquery.knob.min.js"></script>

    <script src="../../dist/plugins/moment/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../dist/plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>

    <script src="../../dist/plugins/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js"></script>

    <script src="../../dist/plugins/summernote/summernote-bs4.min.js"></script>

    <script src="../../dist/plugins/overlayScrollbars/js/jquery.overlayScrollbars.min.js"></script>

    <script src="../../dist/js/adminlte.js?v=3.2.0"></script>

    <script src="../../dist/js/pages/dashboard.js"></script>

    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)

</body>
</html>
```

and here is my view with the datatable:

```
    ViewData["Title"] = "My Projects";
}

@section Scripts2
{
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../dist/plugins/datatables-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../dist/plugins/datatables-responsive/css/responsive.bootstrap4.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../dist/plugins/datatables-buttons/css/buttons.bootstrap4.min.css">
}

<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        <h3 class="card-title">DataTable with default features</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="card-body">
        <div id="example1_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper dt-bootstrap4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                    <div class="dt-buttons btn-group flex-wrap">
                        <button class="btn btn-secondary buttons-copy buttons-html5" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example1" type="button">
                            <span>Copy</span>
                        </button>
                        <button class="btn btn-secondary buttons-csv buttons-html5" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example1" type="button">
                            <span>CSV</span>
                        </button>
                        <button class="btn btn-secondary buttons-excel buttons-html5" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example1" type="button">
                            <span>Excel</span>
                        </button>
                        <button class="btn btn-secondary buttons-pdf buttons-html5" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example1" type="button">
                            <span>PDF</span>
                        </button>
                        <button class="btn btn-secondary buttons-print" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example1" type="button">
                            <span>Print</span>
                        </button>
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button class="btn btn-secondary buttons-collection dropdown-toggle buttons-colvis" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example1" type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span>Column visibility</span>
                                <span class="dt-down-arrow"></span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                    <div id="example1_filter" class="dataTables_filter">
                        <label>Search:<input type="search" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="" aria-controls="example1"></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped dataTable dtr-inline" aria-describedby="example1_info">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="sorting sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="Rendering engine: activate to sort column descending">Rendering engine</th>
                                <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Browser: activate to sort column ascending" style="">Browser</th>
                                <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Platform(s): activate to sort column ascending" style="">Platform(s)</th>
                                <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Engine version: activate to sort column ascending" style="">Engine version</th>
                                <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="CSS grade: activate to sort column ascending" style="">CSS grade</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr class="odd">
                                <td class="dtr-control sorting_1" tabindex="0">Gecko</td>
                                <td style="">Firefox 1.0</td>
                                <td style="">Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
                                <td style="">1.7</td>
                                <td style="">A</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="even">
                                <td class="dtr-control sorting_1" tabindex="0">Gecko</td>
                                <td style="">Firefox 1.5</td>
                                <td style="">Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
                                <td style="">1.8</td>
                                <td style="">A</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="odd">
                                <td class="dtr-control sorting_1" tabindex="0">Gecko</td>
                                <td style="">Firefox 2.0</td>
                                <td style="">Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
                                <td style="">1.8</td>
                                <td style="">A</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="even">
                                <td class="dtr-control sorting_1" tabindex="0">Gecko</td>
                                <td style="">Firefox 3.0</td>
                                <td style="">Win 2k+ / OSX.3+</td>
                                <td style="">1.9</td>
                                <td style="">A</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="odd">
                                <td class="sorting_1 dtr-control" tabindex="0">Gecko</td>
                                <td style="">Camino 1.0</td>
                                <td style="">OSX.2+</td>
                                <td style="">1.8</td>
                                <td style="">A</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="even">
                                <td class="sorting_1 dtr-control" tabindex="0">Gecko</td>
                                <td style="">Camino 1.5</td>
                                <td style="">OSX.3+</td>
                                <td style="">1.8</td>
                                <td style="">A</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="odd">
                                <td class="sorting_1 dtr-control" tabindex="0">Gecko</td>
                                <td style="">Netscape 7.2</td>
                                <td style="">Win 95+ / Mac OS 8.6-9.2</td>
                                <td style="">1.7</td>
                                <td style="">A</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="even">
                                <td class="sorting_1 dtr-control" tabindex="0">Gecko</td>
                                <td style="">Netscape Browser 8</td>
                                <td style="">Win 98SE+</td>
                                <td style="">1.7</td>
                                <td style="">A</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="odd">
                                <td class="sorting_1 dtr-control" tabindex="0">Gecko</td>
                                <td style="">Netscape Navigator 9</td>
                                <td style="">Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
                                <td style="">1.8</td>
                                <td style="">A</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="even">
                                <td class="sorting_1 dtr-control" tabindex="0">Gecko</td>
                                <td style="">Mozilla 1.0</td>
                                <td style="">Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
                                <td style="">1</td>
                                <td style="">A</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">Rendering engine</th>
                                <th rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="">Browser</th>
                                <th rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="">Platform(s)</th>
                                <th rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="">Engine version</th>
                                <th rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="">CSS grade</th>
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-5">
                    <div class="dataTables_info" id="example1_info" role="status" aria-live="polite">Showing 1 to 10 of 57 entries</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7">
                    <div class="dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers" id="example1_paginate">
                        <ul class="pagination">
                            <li class="paginate_button page-item previous disabled" id="example1_previous">
                                <a href="#" aria-controls="example1" data-dt-idx="0" tabindex="0" class="page-link">Previous</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="paginate_button page-item active">
                                <a href="#" aria-controls="example1" data-dt-idx="1" tabindex="0" class="page-link">1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="paginate_button page-item ">
                                <a href="#" aria-controls="example1" data-dt-idx="2" tabindex="0" class="page-link">2</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="paginate_button page-item ">
                                <a href="#" aria-controls="example1" data-dt-idx="3" tabindex="0" class="page-link">3</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="paginate_button page-item ">
                                <a href="#" aria-controls="example1" data-dt-idx="4" tabindex="0" class="page-link">4</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="paginate_button page-item ">
                                <a href="#" aria-controls="example1" data-dt-idx="5" tabindex="0" class="page-link">5</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="paginate_button page-item ">
                                <a href="#" aria-controls="example1" data-dt-idx="6" tabindex="0" class="page-link">6</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="paginate_button page-item next" id="example1_next">
                                <a href="#" aria-controls="example1" data-dt-idx="7" tabindex="0" class="page-link">Next</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts
{
    <script src="../../dist/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../dist/plugins/datatables-bs4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../dist/plugins/datatables-responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../dist/plugins/datatables-responsive/js/responsive.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../dist/plugins/datatables-buttons/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../dist/plugins/datatables-buttons/js/buttons.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../dist/plugins/jszip/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../dist/plugins/pdfmake/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../dist/plugins/pdfmake/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script src="../../dist/plugins/datatables-buttons/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../dist/plugins/datatables-buttons/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../dist/plugins/datatables-buttons/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
    <script>$(function () {
            $("#example1").DataTable({
                "responsive": true, "lengthChange": false, "autoWidth": false,
                "buttons": ["copy", "csv", "excel", "pdf", "print", "colvis"]
            }).buttons().container().appendTo('#example1_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)');
        });</script>
}
```

Here is a photo of what the view currently looks like:
[image: Current View with duplicate buttons bug]

How can I fix the code to remove the duplicate buttons? Also, only the bottom set of buttons/search field work (the top ones do nothing).

Comment: You already has the button,and in script,you added the buttons again

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are Appending the buttons twice. I suggest you to remove the below div.

```
<div class="dt-buttons btn-group flex-wrap">  
... Buttons...
</div>
```